# Flex DataGridColumn display multiline string data

Tags: apache-flex, string, text, multiline, datagridcolumn

Is it possible to display a multiline string in a Flex DataGridColumn?

i.e. Display:

> Text line one.
>
> Text line two.

I've tried putting "\n","\r","`&#13;`" when storing the string but nothing seems to work.

Currently only "Text line one." is displayed and the rest is hidden in the cell. I would prefer not to use "wordWrap=true" to emulate this behaviour in the cell, but instead be able to manually put in newline breaks (although I could turn on wordWrap to avoid long text from hiding due to cell dimensions). Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to create and itemrenderer and use the mx:Text component.  You can then break to a new line using `"&#13;"`, \n, or \r

Comment: Thank you, this works. Takes care of the problem of copying the cell contents too :)

Comment: BTW I had to also set "variableRowHeight=true" in the DataGrid declaration to get multiple lines to display even with the custom renderer. Just FYI to anyone that comes across this.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind. Setting "wordWrap=true" and "variableRowHeight=true" seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether you solve your problem or not but might other can get help.

The perfect solution is to

1. Set `variableRowHeight = true;`
2. Set `wordWrap = true;`
3. For datagrid column use `itemEditor="mx.controls.TextArea";`

Thanks,

Swapnil.